# Gmaps4rails map showing broken controls

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I followed the apneadiving / Google-Maps-for-Rails instructions to add a Google Map to my Rails 4 Bootstrap project.  I first created an empty scaffold project just like in the tutorial video and everything worked great.  Then I added a Google Map to my Bootstrap project and the controls on the map are rendered incorrectly.  I can still zoom in and out but I have to guess where to click as the zoom controls are all messed up and in an incorrect place.

Also, I noticed every time I refresh the page the marker shows up in a slightly different place (by a few houses - sometimes on the next street over).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the css issue, its due to bootstrap, check the wiki: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Twitter-bootstrap-%26-Foundation

For the jumping markers, use version 2.1.2

Comment: for the Map Options which go in the `provider` key, `maxZoom` works but `zoom` doesn't seem to in order to set the initial map zoom level.

Comment: show some code in another question, but options are directly passed to the google map constructor so there shouldnt be any surprise